# How to create child in Firebase database even if it has no values

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I had created the firebase database with some values and to avoid the duplication, I had maintained the other child in the database. This child only gets created if the record gets added if more 1 or more than one record is available. Now my question is how I can create the child even if there is no value in it as I want to write firebase rule for the validation of the data.
Please help.

Comment: You can do that because Firebase Database only exist when value is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using javascript. If so, you can push an object with empty strings as their values. For example:

```
function pushEmptyChildren() {
 var ref = firebase.database().ref('yourDatabase');
 var yourDatabase = {
     childOne: "",
     childTwo:"",
     childThree:""
 }
 ref.push(yourDatabase);
}
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I am using android as client to push the data.

Comment: Ahh can't help you there. But same concept. Just try digging through the docs.